# TortoiseSVN can't merge patch

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am trying to merge a patch but I keep getting the error "." is not a working copy. Changing the directory didn't help.

Thanks.

Comment: You should specify the exact paths and commands that you run.

Answer (score -1):

The error tells that some operation that you perform requires a working copy. However, the directory where you run this operation is not a working copy. Most likely, any other `svn` command will fail with the same error.